# Visual Studio 2012 error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run a opencv program.  I have configured opencv accordingly but I am getting the Visual Studio 2012 error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b)."

Following is the code I am trying to run.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //get the width of frames of the video
    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); 

    //get the height of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); 

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
            break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        if (waitKey(30) == 27) 
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21356654/2662901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not including all of your libraries properly. Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check whether you are missing anything.

Comment: how to use Dependency Walker

Comment: You open your exe file in it. then it will show you all the libraries it uses and it will notify you if any are missing. You can the see those indicated in the tree on the left by red coloring.

Comment: which .exe should i use

Comment: The one that you compiled. Your program.